# javascript why double escape dot/character

Tags: javascript

In js you have to double-escape a dot/character to get an escaped char. That's weird. Why?

js:

```
"." == "." // true
"\." == "." // true
"\\." == "." // false

"\a" == "a" // true
```

In python/php it behaves like expected:

```
"\." == "." // False
```

In js regexes it works other way around, how weird :)

```
"\.".search(/\./)  // no hit
"\\.".search(/\./) // hit
```

**Update**

Like T.J. Crowder correctly mentioned the regex example was wrong. A `\.` regex matches of course a literal dot.

The correct example would be:

```
// Find a literal backslash and a literal dot
"\\.".search(/\\\./) // position 0

// Find a literal Dot
"\\.".search(/\./) // position 1
```

Comment: Unexpected is, that the backslash get's silently dropped.
Seems like i was too much used to python/php-behaviour.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> In js you have to double-escape a dot/character to get an escaped char.

You don't get an "escaped char". You get two characters, a backslash and a dot. The dot is not "escaped."

The sequence `\.` is not special in JavaScript string literals. Any escape sequence other than [the ones defined by the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.8.4) just silently drop the escape character.

Your example `"\." == "."` is `true` because both literals define the same string, which has *one* character (a dot). The invalid escape is ignored.

Your example `"\\." == "."` is `false` because the first literal defines a string with two characters in it (a backslash and a dot), the second defines a string with only one character in it (a dot).

How different languages respond to invalid escape sequences varies by language. Some, like JavaScript, just ignore the invalid escape. Others treat an invalid escape sequence as a backslash followed by the next character, e.g., they silently escape the backslash rather than silently dropping the escape.

---

Re your regex example:

> In js regexes it works other way around, how weird :)
>
> ```
> "\.".search(/\./)  // no hit    <--- Wrong
> "\\.".search(/\./) // hit
> ```

That's incorrect, the first one hits as well (the return value for "no match" is `-1`, not `0`). The return value of `"\.".search(/\./)` is `0` (found a match at index 0, which makes sense, because the `.` is the first character). The return value of `"\\.".search(/\./)` is `1` (found a match at index 1, which makes sense, because the `.` is the *second* character).

And of course, it's quite correct that you escaped the `.` in the regular expression literal, because `.` **is** special in JavaScript regular expressions.

Comment: I added a js-regex example which behaves also different than js-string ;)

Comment: @JensJaehrig: See updated answer, your incorrect about the first regex example not "hitting".